# ыgolang В windows tar.gz сохраняет имена файлов кириллицы кракозябрами

Tags: golang

Создаю файл tar.gz в windows 10 имя файла на русском, но сохраняет не пойми на каком языке... в чем может быть причина?

```
package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "compress/gzip"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var err error
    archive, err := os.Create("puma_config" + ".tar.gz")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    w := gzip.NewWriter(archive)

    tw := tar.NewWriter(w)

    basePath := "./test/"

    filesWrite, err := ioutil.ReadDir(basePath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    for _, file := range filesWrite {
        fileP := basePath + file.Name()
        addToArchive(tw, fileP)
    }

    archive.Close()
    w.Close()
    tw.Close()
}

func addToArchive(tw *tar.Writer, filename string) error {
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    info, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    log.Println(info.Name())
    header, err := tar.FileInfoHeader(info, info.Name())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    header.Name = info.Name()
    err = tw.WriteHeader(header)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    _, err = io.Copy(tw, file)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

[image: файл который сохраняю]
[image: результат]

---

### UPDATE

[image: пустое имя файла]
[image: содержимое сохраняется отлично]
[image: заголовки тоже]

Сами названия файлов пустые из примера @Pak Uula

Скрин примера tar.gz в 7zip
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откройте в вашем архиваторе [архив, который получился из моей программы](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fQJwO6h5GwdDkJAEE5ooBPlj59TahKa9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Про `7z` в интернете пишут, что он не поддерживает интернациональные тары. Вместо юникодных имён он показывает `PaxHeaders`. Поэтому вам нужно открывать такие архивы WinRar-ом.

Comment: @PakUula а почему могу другой tar.gz архив открыть с русскими названиями и все норм? скрин выше приложу последним...

Comment: @PakUula разобрался в ```hdr := &tar.Header{
   Name:   file.Name,
   Mode:   0600,
   Size:   int64(len(file.Body)),
   Format: tar.FormatGNU,
  }``` можно добавить tar.FormatGNU и все работает в 7zip тоже норм

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Разобрался в вашем коде. У вас не в том порядке писатели закрываются.

Должно быть вот так:

```
    tw.Close()
    w.Close()
    archive.Close()
```

Сначала закрыть поток `tar`, затем поток `gzip` и в конце закрыть собственно файл.

В результате получаем вот что:

- Папка `test`
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Содержимое архива
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для проверки в вашем архиваторе прикладываю [получившийся архив](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fQJwO6h5GwdDkJAEE5ooBPlj59TahKa9/view?usp=sharing).

**UPDATE2**

Как выяснилось, не все архиваторы одинаково понимают формат TAR. Архиватор `7z` не поддерживает юникодные пути в архивах. Вместо них он показывает папки `PaxHeaders.nnn`.

**Исходный пост**

Либо вьюер для архивов у вас неправильно имена показывает, либо где-то имена портятся.

Вот контрпример - программа создаёт архив из файлов с именами на кириллице. Программа получена из [примера в документации](https://pkg.go.dev/archive/tar) минимальной переделкой. В созданном архиве должны получиться три файла с именами `ридми.тхт`,`гофер.txt` и `туду.txt`. Созданный архив сохраняется в файл `test.tar`.

```
package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // Create and add some files to the archive.
    f, err := os.Create("test.tar")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tw := tar.NewWriter(f)
    var files = []struct {
        Name, Body string
    }{
        {"ридми.тхт", "Этот архив создан для проверки создания таров из файлов с русскими буковками."},
        {"гофер.txt", "Имена Гофера:\nGeorge\nGeoffrey\nGonzo"},
        {"туду.txt", "Добыть лицензию на разведение животных (придурки!)."},
    }
    for _, file := range files {
        hdr := &tar.Header{
            Name: file.Name,
            Mode: 0600,
            Size: int64(len(file.Body)),
        }
        if err := tw.WriteHeader(hdr); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        if _, err := tw.Write([]byte(file.Body)); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    if err := tw.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    f.Close()

    f, err = os.Open("test.tar")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Open and iterate through the files in the archive.
    tr := tar.NewReader(f)
    for {
        hdr, err := tr.Next()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break // End of archive
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Contents of %s:\n", hdr.Name)
        if _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, tr); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
    f.Close()
}
```

Запускаем: Windows 10, Go 1.16.4, WinRaR 6.00
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имена, как видите, сохранены.

Comment: Добрый день! Спасибо за отзыв! Но к сожалению все еще не сохраняет имена на русском... Приложу скриншоты выше... Запускал ваш пример, ситуация такая же...

Comment: @bsbak я добавил ссылку на архив, который построила программа. Попробуйте в вашем архиваторе

Comment: хм... да, не знал, спасибо!